# Src refspec master does not match any error: failed to push some refs

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bitbucket

I have a VS 2015 project on my local disk, and I wanted to use a code version control system in order to work with somebody else.

He told me to use BitBucket.

I've set up a new repository on BitBucket, and I wanted to put my project into it.

I've therefore download "Git on Windows".
During the installation, I checked "Use Windows command line".
Then I started the cmd, and I ran the following commands:

```
d:\dev\projects\myproject>
git init
git remote add origin https://MYNAME@bitbucket.org/MYREPONAME/OSC.git
git push -u origin master
```

The last command returned the error

```
"error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to "https://MYNAME@bitbucket.org/MYREPONAME/OSC.git""
```

When I type "git branch", nothing is returned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`git init` created an empty repository.  This repository has zero (count them!) commits in it.

`git remote add origin <url>` added what Git calls a *remote*—a short name for another Git repository—to your existing, empty repository.  Your existing repository continues to have zero commits in it.

`git push <remote> <branch>` tells your Git to call up another Git.  Your Git did so.  It then tells you Git to send, to that other Git, all the commits that you have that they don't, that your Git can find on your branch (`master`, in this case).

You still have zero commits.  How many commits do you have, that they don't?

Now, there's an interesting (related) side note: in Git, a branch cannot even *exist* until it has at least one commit on it.  So while you're *on* your `master` branch, your `master` doesn't actually exist.  This explains the precise form of the error message.

The solution is still the same, though: you must add some commit(s) to your repository, on your `master` branch.  The first one you create will cause that branch to actually exist, and once you have some commits that they don't, you will be able to *send* the commits you have, that they don't, to them.

(This does not mean that they will *accept* your commits, just that you will have some to send.  But let's not borrow trouble we don't see yet: first, you probably should create some commits. :-) That is, unless the *other* Git—the one on Bitbucket—already *has* some commits.  In that case, you probably should obtain *theirs*.  But I'm going to assume that they don't have any either.)